# Cdk-table active-row not working after sorting

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I have a cdk-table on one component lets call this A and I have defined actions buttons on the component that contains A lets call this component B. Everything works correctly but when I sort the data on the dataSource the active row is no longer highlighted, I inspected the element and I can see that the active-row class is removed. Changing the route works correctly but the highlight on the table is gone. When I click to view it works correctly.
Here is is how the code looks like

component A

```js
< cdk-table [dataSource] = "MyDataSource" >
  <
  cdk - header - row *
  cdkHeaderRowDef = "columns" >
  </cdk-header-row> <
  a
cdk - row *
  cdkRowDef = "let item; columns: columns" [attr.role] = " 'auxilliary-slider'" [routerLink] = " [
    path,
    {
      outlets: {
        slider: ['slide', 'item', item.id]
      }
    }
  ]
" [routerLinkActive] = "'active-row'" [queryParams] = "test ? queryParams : null"
queryParamsHandling = "merge" >
  <
  cdk - row >
  < /cdk-row> <
  /a> <
  /cdk-table>
```

Component B

```js
< component-a [dataSource] = "dataSource" [actionsTemplate] = "actionsTemplate" >
  </component-b> 
  <ng - template# actionsColumn
let -element = "element" >
  <
  div class = "flex flex-row" >
  <
  dropdown
placement = "bottom-end"
class = "w-full mr-0"#
  [menuTriggerFor] = "tableActions" >
  <
  ng - template# tableActions >
  <
  button(click) = "$event.stopPropagation(); $event.preventDefault();" [routerLink] = "[
path, {
  outlets: {
    slider: ['slide', 'item', item.id, 'edit']
  }
}
]
" [queryParams] = "params"

>
{
  {
    Edit
  }
} <
/button>

<
/ng-template> <
/dropdown> <
/div> <
/ng-template>
```